# Transfer IP address while Server Migration

Tags: ip, migration

I have to migrate my websites from server A to server B.

**Server A (213.171.207.165)**

I have 3 websites running on server A

```
website1.com (213.171.207.235)
website2.co.uk (213.171.207.245)
website3.ae (213.171.207.196)
```

**Server B (88.208.111.55)**

I decided to transfer website1.com (213.171.207.235) to server B. 
My basic question is, can I use the same IP address for my websites in the new server or do I need to get new IP address for the new server within the server's IP range (i.e. 88.208.111.xx)?

I deleted the IP address form the old server and added it in the new server and assigned the domain name to it.

I am using the same nameservers for both dedicated servers. I transferred the IP 20 hours ago (may be it has not been propagated yet)

Just want to make sure it has nothing to do with the IP range.

Thanks

Comment: Although in theory you can add any IP-address to any server, for that IP-address to actually work for the larger internet you depend on the routing protocols to route your IP traffic to your server. That is typically NOT the case when you use an ip-address from another completely different range than what the network was set up with to support.

Comment: What should I do now ? Should I get new IP addresses from the hosting company for the new server and assign domain names to them? What is the easiest way. I am a newbie, server migration/management is not my job but I have been given this task :/

Comment: You already have an ip-address for your new server. You need to update your DNS records so www.example.com and www.example.co.uk no longer point to 213.171.207.165 but to 88.208.111.55. With name based virtual hosting you can host a practically unlimited number of websites on a single ip-address.

Comment: @ali If you are really worried about this IP (which you shouldn't be, as HBruijn's comments explain) you should contact your hosting company. Depending on their infrastructure they might be able to help you. (If it's a virtual environment adding a second subnet to your server can probably, `it depends`, be done, at a small cost)

Comment: I have updated the DNS records. I think I should just wait for the propagation to complete. I was only worried about the IP range. Thanks for your help both HBruijn and Reaces...

Comment: @Reaces: The two ip-addresses are in different AS numbers and most likely are not managed by the same hosting company, making a routing solution improbable.

Comment: @HBruijn I hadn't thought about checking the AS numbers, useful bit of knowledge for the future, thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot transfer IP addresses like that in general. You can only transfer IP addresses if you have control over both networks' Internet-wide routing.

Comment: You are right. I cannot transfer IP addresses like this. I had new IPs available for the new server which I was not given. Thanks for your help.